# The problem of NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Here is my code

```
r:=1.4
solM2:=2.0022
solv2:=26.4404
f:=Sqrt[(r+1)/(r-1)] ArcTan[Sqrt[((r+1)/(r-1))(#^2 -1)]]-ArcTan[Sqrt[(#^2 -1)]]&
put={v3->50.4404,v2->solv2,M2->solM2};
sol=NSolve[v3-v2==f[M3]-f[M2]/.put,M3]
```

Why it's not work? It could not be???

[image]

Figure from my actual note

Edits
[image]

Reason that i think result wrong is by solution of problem.

Comment: From the docs of `NSolve`: "NSolve deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations." Try using `FindInstance` or `FindRoot` instead.

Comment: If use FindRoot , it work with error, but result is worng. Fist time that i use FindInstance, but it also not working.

Comment: Edit the question and include the commands you tried, and the error messages you get, and why you think they are wrong.

Comment: There are no (real) solutions. Define `g[M3_] := Evaluate[(v3 - v2 == f[M3] - f[M2] /. put)[[2]]]`, then check `FunctionDomain[g[a], a]`; you can plot it with `Plot[Evaluate[(v3 - v2 == f[M3] - f[M2] /. put)[[2]]], {M3, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, Automatic}]`, and investigate `Limit[g[a], a -> Infinity]`, which yields `0.043236`. Hence, the function `g` does not attain the value `24`.

Answer (score 2):

[`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) all of the approximate numbers since high precision will be required in [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
r = 1.4 // Rationalize;
solM2 = 2.0022 // Rationalize;
solv2 = 26.4404 // Rationalize;

f := Sqrt[(r + 1)/(r - 1)] ArcTan[Sqrt[((r + 1)/(r - 1)) (#^2 - 1)]] - 
   ArcTan[Sqrt[(#^2 - 1)]] &

put = {v3 -> 50.4404 // Rationalize, v2 -> solv2, M2 -> solM2};
```

[`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) the LHS and RHS of the equation and you will see that there is no solution in the real domain.

```
Plot[Evaluate[{v3 - v2, #[f[M3] - f[M2]]} /. put], {M3, 0, 1}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 20] & /@ {Re, Im, Abs}
```

[image]

Using the imaginary or absolute value of the RHS

```
sol1 = FindRoot[Evaluate[v3 - v2 == Abs[f[M3] - f[M2]] /. put], {M3, 0.9`20}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N

(*  {M3 -> 0.912871}  *)

sol2 = FindRoot[Evaluate[v3 - v2 == Im[f[M3] - f[M2]] /. put], {M3, 0.9`20}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N

(*  {M3 -> 0.912871}  *)
```